# After disabling passwords on remote TeamViewer, why does local TeamViewer still demand password for remote TeamViewer?

Tags: teamviewer

Screenshots 1 and 2 prove that remote computer forwent and removed all passwords.

[image]

[image]

Screenshot 3 proves that remote computer confirmed no "One-Time Password", and that remote computer's TeamViewer is ready to connect!

[image]

Screenshot 4 proves that local computer's TeamViewer still requires a password to access remote computer, even though remote computer dispensed with passwords!

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just set a password then configure the password to be remembered within your own session of Teamviwer.  Of course the only way I would suggest that is to log into Teamvierwer and make sure you have 2FA enabled.

Comment: “Because I am shunning passwords? I don't need any password.” For TeamViewer only? Or just in general? Or just in this case?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Because I am shunning passwords for just TeamViewer? I don't need any password on any TeamViewer.

Comment: @user I doubt that TeamViewer has an option to connect without any password since remote access clients typically need credentials to begin with. So the idea that the developers would do an end-run around basic authentication would not even occur to them. I mean, if one could trigger password-less access then that could be an attack vector for hacking and such. Look at this [FBI advisory](https://www.zdnet.com/article/following-oldsmar-attack-fbi-warns-about-using-teamviewer-and-windows-7/) after a barely protected TeamViewer instance lead to a public utility being hacked.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 *"I doubt that TeamViewer has an option to connect without any password".* **But see my screenshot 2! Why would developers provide an option for "Disabled (no random password)"?**

Comment: @user Fair enough. Have you considered contacting TeamViewer support to see if they can assist? It could be this is a feature that once worked and then stopped working and nobody told them? Seriously. Stuff like this happens.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 TeamViewer supports merely paid accounts, not free accounts. And I cannot afford a paid TeamViewer account. Do you have a paid account? Can you ask for me please?